# Is this a valid MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got 4 tables: users, messages, files, notes. I want to make a query which will delete all of a users' stuff if he's deleted. Will the following work:

```
DELETE FROM users, messages, files, notes WHERE userId = '$userId'
```

All 4 tables have got the column `userId`

Comment: You said "will the following work?" Why don't you try yourself first?

Comment: @Naveed I didn't see a rule anywhere on this site that you're taxed when I ask a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the statements in to four separate statements, in order to delete the rows associated with the userid.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE userId = '$userId'
DELETE FROM messages WHERE userId = '$userId'
DELETE FROM files WHERE userId = '$userId'
DELETE FROM notes WHERE userId = '$userId'
```

The other alternative would be to cascade the deletes across the foreign keys.

When you create a foreign key you can choose what you want to do to the child records on the deletion of a parent record.  This is denoted below by specifying the ON Delete in the creation of the foreign key.  Here is some reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE  u, m, f, p
FROM    users u
LEFT JOIN
        messages m
ON      m.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
        files f
ON      f.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
        posts p
ON      p.user_id = u.id
WHERE   u.id = 1
```

This assumes that the record with `id = 1` exists in `users`, otherwise nothing will be deleted.

Note, however, that this is not very efficient and four separate deletes will work better.

Comment: @Johan: because an inner join would not delete anything if there is no record with `user_id = 1` in at least one table.

Answer (score 1):

in the where statement, if you have more than one table reference, you should refer to TABLE.COLUMN,
eg :  `WHERE users.userid = '$userId'.`

I recommend to do 1 sentence per table

Answer (score 1):

In your WHERE, you have userId = '$userId'.  Other people can correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that the userId would be ambiguous and this statement wouldn't run. @John Hartsocks answer should work though if that is indeed the case.

That is besides the point though.  If you're worried about making sure a user is completely deleted, then you should be using foreign key constraints.  You said when you delete a user, you want to make sure that all information pertaining to that user is deleted.  If you add the FK constraint to every table that has a user id (besides the users table, in which case it would have the primary key constraint), it should not be possible for you to delete a user, without first making sure all other data referencing that user is deleted.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the $userId, I was referring to the userId on the left side as ambiguous.  Even though people might look at that and think it works, I'm pretty sure mySQL would not execute the statement.  I'm sure on the php side, it would build the query (read: string) properly.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: No. The documentation you linked to suggests that a USING clause must be used when deleting from multiple tables.

Comment: Err.. no..Multiple-table syntax:

    DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
       tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
       FROM table_references
       [WHERE where_condition]

Comment: Any chance of undoing all that negativity?

Comment: To remove the down votes? I tried but it can't be done unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Aha, turns out I can edit it myself; so one down-vote removed